# How to compare between two dates and make timer countdown between them in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, datetime

i'm trying to make countdown `NSTimer` between future date and current date and this update appearing in view.

**for example if current date is 25/4/2019
and future date will be 30/4/2019
that will be a count down timer 5d:2h:50m:20s**

i used some code

```
  @IBOutlet weak var btnTimeLabel : UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 0.1 // change 2 to desired number of seconds
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.countDownDate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }

    }


    @objc func countDownDate() {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy" //Your date format
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00") //Current time zone
        let futuredate = dateFormatter.date(from: "29-4-2019") //according to date format your date string
        var calendar = Calendar.current
        let diffDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date(), to: futuredate!)
        print (Date())
        print(diffDateComponents)
        let countdown = "Days \(String(describing:diffDateComponents.day!)),  Hours: \(String(describing: diffDateComponents.hour!)), Minutes: \(String(describing: diffDateComponents.minute!)), Seconds: \(String(describing: diffDateComponents.second!))"
        print("countdown",countdown)
        var dayText = String(describing: diffDateComponents.day!) + "d "
        var hourText = String(describing: diffDateComponents.hour!) + "h "
        btnTimeLabel.setTitle(dayText + hourText + String(describing: diffDateComponents.minute!) + "m " + String(describing: diffDateComponents.second!) + "s", for: .normal)
        //print(dayText + hourText + String(describing: diffDateComponents.minute!) + "m " + String(describing: diffDateComponents.second!) + "s")
    }        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

it give me wrong timer

Comment: Replace most of your code with the use of `DateComponentsFormatter` passing in the two dates.

Comment: Also note that you probably don't want GMT timezone unless you really do want the countdown to be from "now" local time to midnight GMT on April 29, 2019.

Comment: please can you give me more explanation with code example &  thank you for helping

Comment: Do a search on `DateComponentsFormatter`.

Comment: i used DateComponentsFormatter it give me wrong time (  -2mo 3w 6d -10:23:44)

Comment: Swap the dates.

Comment: i do it ,the output is (2mo 3w 6d 10:32:48)

Comment: i need the output to be just 4 days

Comment: Then you must be passing in the wrong dates.

Comment: you mean the format of date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my version of using **DateComponentsFormatter** to get the time difference

Set up the **DateComponentsFormatter**

```
let dcf = DateComponentsFormatter()
dcf.allowedUnits = [.day, .hour, .minute, .second]
dcf.unitsStyle = .full
```

Set up ordinary date formatter

```
let df = ISO8601DateFormatter()
df.formatOptions = [.withFullDate, .withDashSeparatorInDate]
```

Perform formatting

```
if let future = df.date(from: "2019-04-29"), let diff = dcf.string(from: Date(), to: future) {
    print(diff)
}
```

Output is

> 3 days, 6 hours, 9 minutes, 9 seconds